# RDS - Cant connect to database

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

**Hello,**

I have created a RDS database server. A few day earlier everything worked perfectly, but now i just cant connect to it.

I have tried things like changing an inbound rule to 0.0.0.0/0, but nothing worked.

Any ideas how to fix it?
Thanks!

Comment: If you open up the database by using 0.0.0.0/0 - double check the endpoint, user name and password. Make sure nothing was changed by mistake

Comment: Its usually a setting like that when it all of a sudden stops working

Answer (score 0):

**It was my problem.**

I had set up a ssl certificate in mysql workbench, so it didn't worked.

Thanks for help.